# Bootstrap 3 dropdown menu item in firefox - after click going to url

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on 3 level navigation menu.

I find great example of menu on http://bootply.com/92442 which works pretty cool, but when I insert url addresses to the code the drop-down menu item don't open sub menu, but going to url. Here is example: http://bootply.com/109393

It only happens on firefox browser. On Chrome and Opera everything is ok.

Comment: Why would you add a link if it is not supposed to be clicked?

Comment: the menu is generated by cms

Comment: ReferenceError: blurLink is not defined

Comment: You have right I insert into TYPO3 noBlur = 1